# Reformat number inside array of string PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, number-formatting

I have an array which contains strings like this:

```
$items = array(
  "Receive 10010 from John",
  "Send 1503000 to Jane",
  "Receive 589 from Andy",
  "Send 3454 to Mary"
);
```

i want to reformat the number inside this array so it will become like this:

```
$items = array(
  "Receive 10.010 from John",
  "Send 1.503.000 to Jane",
  "Receive 589 from Andy",
  "Send 3.454 to Mary"
);
```

if i use `number_format` function it will look like this with number varibale:

```
$number = '412223';
number_format($number,0,',','.');
echo $number; //412.223
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to match a number inside a string and apply some custom formatting. For a single string, this would look like this:

```
$string = "Receive 10010 from John";

$formatted = preg_replace_callback( "/[0-9]+/", function ($matches) {
    return number_format($matches[0], 0, ',', '.');
}, $string);

echo $formatted;
```

> Receive 10.010 from John

---

If you want to apply the same logic to your entire array, you can wrap the above in a call to [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$formatted = array_map(function ($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback( "/[0-9]+/", function ($matches) {
        return number_format($matches[0], 0, ',', '.');
    }, $string);
}, $items);

print_r($formatted);
```

> Array
>       (
>           [0] => Receive 10.010 from John
>           [1] => Send 1.503.000 to Jane
>           [2] => Receive 589 from Andy
>           [3] => Send 3.454 to Mary
>       )

Answer (score 1):

There you go

Follow the following steps

1. Run through the loop using foreach
2. Extract the numbers using preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
3. Apply number format number_format($matches[0],0,',','.');
4. update array items

So the whole story is to use preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches); and extract the string number.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't expect decimal numbers, you could also use something like

```
$items = preg_replace('/\d\K(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)/', ".", $items);
```

- `\d` is a [shorthand](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for digit `[0-9]`
- [`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match
- after every digit the [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)` checks if there are [multiples](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) of three digits ahead until the next [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (end of the number).

See [regex demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/h67Nln/2) or [php demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/1040625)